# Использование побочного потока

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой зависания формы при вычислениях в основном потоке, почитал, узнал что метод вычисления можно пустить вторым потоком. Использую:

```cs
Thread tr = new Thread(Calculate);
tr.Start();
```

Код Calculate:

```cs
public static void Calculate()
{
    date = mainForm.inputData;
    int number = logicClass.searchNumber(date);
    res = logicClass.Alg1logic(number);
    res2 = logicClass.Alg2logic(number);
    res3 = logicClass.Alg3logic(number);
    res5 = logicClass.Alg5Logic(number);
    res4 = logicClass.Alg4Logic(number);
}
```

Данный метод считает 5 массивов значений, а результат функции, элемент с определенным номером, записывает в поле `public`. (массивы тоже `public` и инициализируются внутри каждого метода)

Проблема состоит в том, что при дальнейшем использовании массива оказывается, что все они имеют значение `null`. Соответственно, массивы не инициализируются, и значения не пишутся. Получается, что то, что выполняется во втором потоке, никак не затрагивают, то, что было объявлено в основном. Необходимо, чтобы при вычислении данных в побочном потоке  переменные получали значения, вычисленные там же, и с ними можно было работать далее из основного.

Если можно еще как-то решить проблему с зависанием формы, то такой вариант тоже подойдет. (переменные и массивы статические)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему: метод, в котором вызываем задачу делаем async, и применяем следующий код:

```cs
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    int number = logicClass.searchNumber(date);
    result1 = logicClass.Alg1logic(number);
    result2 = logicClass.Alg2logic(number);
    result3 = logicClass.Alg3logic(number);
    result5 = logicClass.Alg5Logic(number);
    result4 = logicClass.Alg4Logic(number);
    //... (используем полученные данные тут же)
});
```

Метод, в котором вызвали task вызываем как await

В общем виде получаем:

```cs
public async static Task RealisationLogic()
{
    date = mainForm.inputData;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int number = logicClass.searchNumber(date);
        result1 = logicClass.Alg1logic(number);
        result2 = logicClass.Alg2logic(number);
        result3 = logicClass.Alg3logic(number);
        result5 = logicClass.Alg5Logic(number);
        result4 = logicClass.Alg4Logic(number);
        rmseClass.Init();
        rmseClass.searchRMSE();
        rmseClass.searchRMSE1();
        rmseClass.searchRMSE5();
        rmseClass.searchRMSE3();
        rmseClass.searchRMSE4();
    });
}
```

В основном коде программы вызываем как:

```cs
await Program.RealisationLogic();
```